# What is the type casting hierarchy in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql, casting, union

Taking the following example:

```
WITH tbl as (
    select 1, 1e2, 1.2e-4, 1.235, null, 0b01, if(1=1, 1, 2) union
    select 1, 1e2, 1.2e-4, 1.235, null, 0b01, if(1=1, 1, 2.4) union
    select 1, 1e2, 1.2e-4, 1.235, null, 0b01, if(1=1, 1, 'a')
)
select * from tbl
```

If I only include the first `select` statement in the `cte`, the type will be `int`. If I include the first and second, the type will be `DECIMAL`, and if I include all three, the type will be cast to `VARCHAR` (regardless of position of the three statements).

How does mysql determine which type to cast it to -- where can I find the 'type hierarchy'? Do most other DBMS handle this the same, or is it different for each?

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/type-conversion.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, to ask the question about other databases, you need to express the SQL using standard SQL -- that is using a `case` expression rather than `if`:

```
with tbl as (
    select 1, 1e2, 1.2e-4, 1.235, null, 0b01, (case when 1=1 then 1 else 2 end) union
    select 1, 1e2, 1.2e-4, 1.235, null, 0b01, (case when 1=1 then 1 else 2.4 end) union
    select 1, 1e2, 1.2e-4, 1.235, null, 0b01, (case when 1=1 then 1 else 'a' end)
)
select * from tbl;
```

In almost any database, the third row is going to generate an error.  The `case` expression has two paths, one returns an `int` and one returns a string.  By the rules of standard SQL, the type of the `case` expression is an `int` and you get a type conversion error.  The *type* of the expression has nothing to do with which value is returned.

MySQL, however, deviates from the standard.  In this case, it allows the type to be a string.

A similar thing occurs with the `union`.  It verifies that the types are compatible and determines the appropriate type.  Because most databases return an error for the third subquery, the type conversion is irrelevant in that case.

However, it is relevant when you consider the first two.  The types are different in the first two (int versus numeric/decimal).  These are generally compatible, so the `numeric/decimal` is the returned type from the union -- and there is no error.

I should note that some databases play tricks.  SQL Server, for instance, would allow your code but it would return a decimal.  Why?  It eliminates the `case` expression during the *parsing* phase, so it never considers returning a string.  That said, it would generate an error if you using `1=0`.

Answer (score 1):

All members of an `union all` query must have matching column datatypes: the way you write the query, the datatabse needs to make a decision on which datatype should be used for the last column.

> How does mysql determine which type to cast it to -- where can I find the 'typer hierarchy'?

When asked to compare values of different datatypes, MySQL goes through a heuristic that is [described in the documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/type-conversion.html) that juergen d commented. In a nutshell, if you are mixing numbers and strings, they end up compared as (floating-point) numbers. That's the last bullet point in the list, which is kind of a catch-all:

> - In all other cases, the arguments are compared as floating-point (real) numbers. For example, a comparison of string and numeric operands takes place as a comparison of floating-point numbers.

You also asked:

> Do most other DBMS handle this the same, or is it different for each?

Not all databases have the same decision tree. There are also dabatases where your statement would simply fail, because of inconsistent datatype (Postgres is one example).

Take away: do not rely on implicit conversion (left apart, simple, unambigous cases). Know your datatypes, and perform explicit casts to the proper datatype when needed. This makes the query much more explicit about what it ought to do, and saves you (and the future readers and maintainers of your code) the burden of remembering the implicit casting rules of your database.